# Installing breach browser

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, scripts, chromium

EDIT: Just look at the accepted answer. I wasn't how it worked at the time of writing so I just guessed below.

I am new to Linux so this might be a noob question. I am trying to install a new web browser called [breach](https://github.com/breach/breach_core) which is built in JavaScript specifically Node.js, and I wanted to try hacking on it a little bit.

I installed the tar folder from off of their site and I have a folder called **AUTO_UPDATE_BUNDLE** and a file called breach.sh I believe the breach file is a bash script and I was guessing that's how I install it. (I have no idea if that's correct though.)

So I looked up online how to run a bash script.  I went in the terminal and this is what I wrote while in the directory of the breach.sh file.

```
sh breach
```

I got this error.

```
[3428:3428:0710/191300:858123323:FATAL:browser_main_loop.cc(172)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I then navigated to the link to [code.google.com/...](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment) above and it said

> We need a SUID helper binary to turn on the sandbox on Linux.
>
> In most cases, you can run build/update-linux-sandbox.sh and it'll
>   install the proper sandbox for you in /usr/local/sbin and tell you to
>   update your .bashrc if needed.

I don't understand how I can run `build/update-linux-sandbox.sh`. Is build a directory in my root directory? I tried searching for it there but I couldn't find it.

I would appreciate any help, and if I'm heading the wrong direction with properly installing this browser than correct me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you need a setuid sandbox to run `breach` you basically have two options:

1. Use the one provided by chromium-brower (recommended method):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
   ```

   Go to the `breach` folder (e.g `breach-v0.3.20-alpha.5-linux-x64`) and type the following command:

   ```
   CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome-sandbox ./breach
   ```
2. Follow the instructions provided here: [Building Breach from Source](https://github.com/breach/breach_core/wiki/Building-Breach-from-Source).

   Note that you'll first have to [build the ExoBrowser](https://github.com/breach/exo_browser/wiki/Building-the-ExoBrowser).

   As you need the `chromium` source code to build it, use the chromium [`depot_tools`](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools) `fetch` command to get it.

[image]

**UPDATE**:

If (like me) you have downloaded the breach alpha in your `~/Downloads` folder you can set an alias to run `breach` as follow:

```
alias breach='export CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome-sandbox && ~/Downloads/breach-v0.3.20-alpha.5-linux-x64/breach'
```

Copy this command to your `~/.bashrc` to keep this alias.

Note: adjust the path to the `breach` startup script for your needs.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.  I got it installed, but one question. Do I have to run this command `CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome-sandbox ./breach` every time I want to start breach up? Is there a way to build a shortcut or something? Even a reference would be nice.

Comment: @John: I've updated my answer with an alias to put in your `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 3):

If you have google chrome installed, do

```
export CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox
```

just before you run breach with

```
./breach
```

Essentially, this is a shortcut to running build/update-linux-sandbox.sh mentioned [there](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment#Installation_instructions_for_developers).